# Open file window buttons for multiple file select with SWF multiple file upload

Tags: flash, swfupload

I am using SWFUpload to upload multiple files at once.

But I notices that on FireFox and Opera the "Open file window" has button "Save" instead of "Open".
[image]

IE and Chrome has "Open".

Is there a way to change the button from "Save" to "Open"?

Thank you.

Comment: If you upload files, you don't really open them right? So I don't understand the reason of the question?

Comment: poepje: when using <input type="file" name="name"> and press on browse you get a window with OPEN button. The users are familiar with "OPEN" button and I want to make the flash upload as mush as possible intuitive and similar to a classic upload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `actionscript`, the only things, you can customize in `Open/Save` dialog, are `file-type filters` and `default filename`(when saving). So there is no way for changing labels on buttons.